# Neo4j, Cypher return results as was an unexisting relation between nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to represent a path of the graph that a ***person may_knows*** a **person** if they has same friends.
When i run this query i got exactly the results i want in table mode.

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:IS_FRIEND_OF]->(any:Person)
MATCH (p2:Person)-[:IS_FRIEND_OF]->(any)
WHERE NOT p1 = p2
RETURN p1, p2
```

My problem is that i want to represent them as graph and the relation that connects person1 and person2 rename it as "**MAY_KNOWS**"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `virtual relationships` in APOC :

```
MATCH (n:Person)-[r:IS_FRIEND_OF]->(other)  
MATCH (other)-[:IS_FRIEND_OF]->(candidate)
WHERE NOT (n)-[:IS_FRIEND_OF]->(candidate)   
RETURN n, other, candidate, apoc.create.vRelationship(n, 'MAY_KNOW', {}, candidate)
```

Reference : https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_virtual_nodes_rels

[image]

Comment: It help me to way i have to follow but you know why print me that error(my neo4j version is 3.2): Unknown function 'apoc.create.vRelationship' (line 4, column 29 (offset: 170))
"RETURN n, other, candidate, apoc.create.vRelationship(n, 'MAY_KNOW', {}, candidate)"

Comment: did you install APOC ?

Comment: No i can't, Currenty iu use neo4j CE ver:3.0.4 and did not support it. From neo4j site i can't even find newer version installer expect Neo4j Desktop edition that  i do not need in my case

Comment: Finnaly i found it, It work fine for me eith code:
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:IS_FRIEND_OF]->(any:Person)
MATCH (p2:Person)-[:IS_FRIEND_OF]->(any)
WHERE NOT p1 = p2 and NOT (p1)-[:IS_FRIEND_OF]->(p2) and NOT (p2)-[:IS_FRIEND_OF]->(p1)
RETURN p1,p2, apoc.create.vRelationship(p1, 'MAY_KNOW', {}, p2)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your issue. Thanks